# PHP mailer to send simple contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, mailer

I've been trying to use the mail() function with PHP but can't seem to get a message to send to my email address when I test the contact form.  It simply goes to a white screen and no further.. It doesn't even show the success message underneath.

This is the PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = 'Message from Reef website';
$to = 'myemail@hotmail.co.uk';

if (empty($name) || empty($address) || empty($number) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
    if (empty($name))
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your Full Name";
    if (empty($name))
        $error['address'] = "Please enter your address";
    if (empty($name))
        $error['number'] = "Please enter a contact number";
    if (empty($email))
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid Email Address";
    if (empty($message))
        $error['message'] = "Please write a message, enquiries or other concerns above";
}
else { //if not empty

    $headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    $success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
}
}
?>
```

This is  my HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="mailer.php">
    <table border="1">
            <tr>
    <td><label for="name" class="g">Name</label></td>
    <td><input id="name" name="name" type="text" required autofocus></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="address" class="g">Address</label></td>
    <td><textarea rows="3" id="address" name="address" cols="50"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="number" class="g">Contact number</label></td>
    <td><input id="number" name="text" type="text" required autofocus></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td><label for="email" class="g">Email</label></td>
      <td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="example@domain.com" required autofocus></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td><label for="message" class="g">Enquiry</label></td>
      <td><textarea rows="3" id="message" name="message" cols="50"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Can anyone see what's missing? Looking at other similar questions, there's are all like mine but they say that they work.

Comment: Thats because you are not echoing any of the error..echo them you will know what is the error..

Comment: Use error_reporting(e_all); in the first line and give us errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's going to a blank page is that the PHP page is blank! You don't seem to be echoing your success message anywhere on the page.

I would recommend changing your form so that the HTML is as below:

```
<form method="POST">
```

And then paste the PHP into the top of that page. Remember to set the page type to .php rather than .html/.htm

Finally add an echo to the top of your form so the success message will display, along the lines of

```
<?php
    if ($success) {
        echo $success;
    }
?>
```

Comment: great! thanks. It's now working except the PHP success message breaks the page and displays up in the left hand corner? But at least it sends to the email now!

Comment: In which case add some more html around the success message such as <?php
    if ($success) {
        echo "<div class='classname'>".$success."</div>";
    }
?> And then target that class in your css

Answer (score 1):

```
if (empty($name))
    $error['name'] = "Please enter your Full Name";
if (empty($name))
    $error['address'] = "Please enter your address";
if (empty($name))
    $error['number'] = "Please enter a contact number";
```

You are using `$name` in every `if`statement. Change it with corresponding variable.

**AND**

Change
`<input id="number" name="text" type="text" required autofocus>`

To `<input id="number" name="number" type="text" required autofocus>`

I think you got it. You are checking `empty($number)` in parent `if` statement which is always `true`, And you are not getting any message because of wrong variable (`$name`).

Comment: Thanks this has definitely helped

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

to

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
  echo "mail has been sent";
}
else
{
 echo "error during sending mail";
}
```

also change your ifs because you check only one variable

```
if (empty($name))
```

always $name

put in your first line for debuging:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

why do you use "id" is it necessary for you?

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" required autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the SMTP server settings in your php.ini file? You need to have an SMTP server running to send mail.

An easier solution would be to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

You have one problem

You are trying to access number value like this

```
$number = $_POST['number'];
```

but in your form it is name="text"

```
<input id="number" name="text" type="text" required autofocus>
```

so change the form field to this

```
<input id="number" name="number" type="text" required autofocus>
```

that was causing your validation to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't have set SMTP data in php.ini
If you can, use some other library to send mail like https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer